# Setting credentials for showing static image from Amazon S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

In my Rails app I want to show static imaged from my AWS S3 bucket. So there is no need to have a solution like Paperclip or Carrierwave, because there is no uploading involved. So I use the `aws-sdk` gem to interact with the S3 bucket.

This works (of course) fine for public images, but when I want to show private images I get an `access denied`. I have set the following environment variables: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and S3_BUCKET_NAME.

On Heroku I have added these environment variables with `heroku config:set` and locally I use the `dotenv` gem.

The problem is that I still have the `access denied` error, both locally and on Heroku. What is the problem here? This is the view (with a static URL, later this will of course be dynamic):

```
  = link_to "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mybucket/Demo/20160503092647717.png" do
    = image_tag("https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mybucket/Demo/20160503092647717.png", width: '600')
```

Comment: Have you set the permission of the manually uploaded pics to be visible for anybody?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

S3 bucket by default is PRIVATE, only accessible through the owner access key.

You can make the bucket public access without required access key by setting the Principal to "*" and attach to bucket policies.

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"AddPerm",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"],
      "Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {"aws:SourceIp": "54.240.143.0/24"},
        "NotIpAddress": {"aws:SourceIp": "54.240.143.188/32"} 
  }   
    }
  ]
}
```

Above "condition" can restrict which IP address can access your S3 bucket.

There is many way you can grant the bucket to be update or view by other via strict policies and access control. You need to read through and configure them. 
Please check here : [S3 example bucket policies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you can easily control access on the Amazon side too.

Comment: @John : Just beware that the restriction in AWS as well, e.g. condition restriction for source IP doesn't work for VPC private IP address.

Answer (score 0):

You can't solve that by adding your AWS credentials to your server. You are sending the client/browser only the link to the protected resource. You either have to make the resources public or for a little added security you can create new Access Keys which have read access to the bucket and use the [AWS JS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html) and serve the newly created credentials to your visitors.